# Get the entity that represents the current user [symfony2]

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

How do I get the email address of the current user ?

To retrieved the Username or user id is easy , but i didn't found any example that explain how to get the email address of the current use.

```
$entity = new Post();
 $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
            $usr = $userManager->findUserByUsername($this->container->get('security.context')
                ->getToken()
                ->getUser());

            $entity->setUsername($usr);
```

Comment: You can create a query to get the Email of the current user using the Id. But I don't know if it's the easiest way

Answer (score 2):

In controller (that extends symfony controller)

```
$this->getUser();
```

For services you need to inject security.token_storage service and use

```
$this->tokenStorage()->getToken()->getUser()
```

**TokenStorage::getToken()** can return null, consider it!